# I want to best hide a CardView Order request from layout

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, hide

I'm using setValue(View.INVISIBLE with several references hosted in firebase:

```
holder.txtOrderId.setText(adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                holder.txtOrderStatus.setText(Common.convertCodeToStatus(model.getStatus()));
                holder.txtOrderAddress.setText(model.getAddress());
                holder.txtOrderPhone.setText(model.getPhone());       holder.txtOrderDate.setText(Common.getDate(Long.parseLong(adapter.getRef(position).getKey())));
                holder.txtPaymentMethod.setText(model.getPaymentMethod());
                holder.txtPaymentState.setText(model.getPaymentState());
                holder.txtName.setText(model.getName());
                holder.txtTotal.setText(model.getTotal());
```

i want it to just disappear without deleting from firebase, disappear in this layout, it disappears but it disappears for whoever makes the request too (dont want this), and be able to eliminate it in another layout I have(its works) and crashes next time you go to orders in both layouts.

```
holder.btnHide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        hideOrder(adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                    }
                });
```

After:hideOrder

```
private void hideOrder(final String key) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(OrderStatus.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Olá, "+Common.currentUser.getName());
        alertDialog.setMessage("O pedido foi entregue?");
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                reuests.child(key).setValue(View.INVISIBLE);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(OrderStatus.this, "Pedido finalizado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Não", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(OrderStatus.this, "Cancelado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.mipmap.picture);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

I don't know how to do it, can anyone help me?

Comment: If you consider at some point in time try using [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/), here you can find an article called, [How to delete a record from Firestore on a RecylerView left/right swipe?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-a-record-from-firestore-on-a-recylerview-left-right-swipe-d65d993f0baf) or [How to delete multiple records from Firestore using RecyclerView multi-selection?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-delete-multiple-records-from-firestore-using-recyclerview-multi-selection-96108e4c6166) might help.

Comment: use `binding.yourCardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);` It hide your `cardView`.

Comment: @AlexMamo he just wants to disappear not wants to delete it from `FireBase`. He already mentioned this in their question.

Comment: @MDev thanks i wil try that :)

Comment: @MDev i have to enable binding on project and it will work?

Comment: @LeandroMendes can I know where you want to use it? Adapter or Activity. If you are using an adapter then set id to your `cardView` and make its `findViewById` in `viewHolder` and in `onBindViewHolder` use it as with `holder` as here `holder.yourCardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);`. If you not understand, let me know I explain it in `Answer`.

Comment: @MDev yes its 'adapter', i already make 'findViewById' but not on 'viewHolder' .. i dont have this, 'onBindViewHolder'

Comment: @LeandroMendes ok just use it. use this code `yourCardViewID.setVisibility(View.GONE);` when & where you want to hide your `card View`.

Comment: @MDev i makes the id on 'ViewHolder' buts its the same results, apps crashes, and on log cat give me 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.CardView.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.thunderbolt_108.serverapp.OrderStatus$3.onClick(OrderStatus.java:200)

Comment: @LeandroMendes I cannot understand where you are using this card view. Please add code of that activity or Adapter where you are using `CardView` so that we can understand.

Comment: here @MDev https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71938807/best-way-to-make-cardview-hide