# Best way to make CardView hide

Tags: java, android, hide, android-cardview

this CardView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardv"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                    <TextView
                        android:text="Data:"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/order_date"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:text="Order Date"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                    <TextView
                        android:text="Nº de pedido:"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/order_id"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:text="#111111"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                    <TextView
                        android:text="Nome:"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/userName"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:text="Name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                    <TextView
                        android:text="Contacto:"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/order_phone"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:text="123456789"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                    <TextView
                        android:text="Morada:"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/order_address"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:text="Address"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                    <TextView
                        android:text="Metodo de pagamento:"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/paymentMethod"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:text="Payment Method"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                    <TextView
                        android:text="Estado de pagamento:"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/paymentState"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:text="Payment State"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                    <TextView
                        android:text="Estado do pedido:"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/order_status"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:text="Status"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                    <TextView
                        android:text="Total:"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/totalAmount"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
                        android:textAllCaps="true"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                        android:text="Total Amount"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>



        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
                android:text="Estado"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:cornerRadius="5dp"
                app:fButtonColor="@android:color/holo_red_light"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
                android:id="@+id/btnHide"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="Hide"
                android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
                android:text="Finalizr"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                app:cornerRadius="5dp"
                app:fButtonColor="@android:color/holo_blue_light" />

            <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
                android:id="@+id/btnDetail"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="Detalhes"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
                app:cornerRadius="5dp"
                app:fButtonColor="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
                android:id="@+id/btnDirection"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:text="Direções"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
                app:cornerRadius="5dp"
                app:fButtonColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

appears in this list:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bgencomendeas"
        tools:context=".OrderStatus">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/voltar2"
            android:layout_width="65dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/fbutton_color_transparent"
            android:text="Voltar"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
        <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgAndroidInstalike2"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="98dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/instalike2"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="297dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="595dp" />
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
            android:id="@+id/listOrders"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I declared in ViewHolder :

```
public class OrderViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    public TextView txtOrderId,txtOrderStatus,txtOrderPhone,txtOrderAddress,txtOrderDate,txtPaymentState,txtPaymentMethod,txtName,txtTotal;
    public Button btnEdit,btnHide,btnRemove,btnDetail,btnDirection;
    public CardView cardlayoutadapter;
    
    public OrderViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        txtOrderAddress=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_address);
        txtOrderId=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_id);
        txtOrderStatus=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_status);
        txtOrderPhone=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_phone);
        txtOrderDate=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.order_date);
        txtPaymentState=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.paymentState);
        txtPaymentMethod=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.paymentMethod);
        txtName=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.userName);
        txtTotal=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.totalAmount);

        btnEdit=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnEdit);
        btnRemove=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnRemove);
        btnHide=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnHide);
        btnDetail=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDetail);
        btnDirection=(Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDirection);

        cardlayoutadapter = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardv);
    }

}
```

when I click the btnHide button it goes to "private void hideOrder" to make sure I want to make it disappear after completing the order, and this is where I wanted to somehow make the cardview disappear with that data, so it's not there to occupy , I have another "layout that makes eliminate", either in GONE or invisibility or put the parameter layout_height == 0

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        CalligraphyConfig.initDefault(new CalligraphyConfig.Builder()
                .setDefaultFontPath("fonts/Vahika.ttf")
                .setFontAttrId(R.attr.fontPath)
                .build());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_order_status);



@Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull OrderViewHolder holder, final int position, @NonNull final Request model) {
                holder.txtOrderId.setText(adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                holder.txtOrderStatus.setText(Common.convertCodeToStatus(model.getStatus()));
                holder.txtOrderAddress.setText(model.getAddress());
                holder.txtOrderPhone.setText(model.getPhone());
                holder.txtOrderDate.setText(Common.getDate(Long.parseLong(adapter.getRef(position).getKey())));
                holder.txtPaymentMethod.setText(model.getPaymentMethod());
                holder.txtPaymentState.setText(model.getPaymentState());
                holder.txtName.setText(model.getName());
                holder.txtTotal.setText(model.getTotal());

holder.btnHide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        hideOrder(adapter.getRef(position).getKey());
                    }
                });

 private void hideOrder(final String key) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(OrderStatus.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Olá, "+Common.currentUser.getName());
        alertDialog.setMessage("O pedido foi entregue?");
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                //linearcardv
                //reuests.child(key).removeValue();
                //binding.CardView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                //reuests.child(key).setValue(View.INVISIBLE);

                cardlayoutadapter.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(OrderStatus.this, "Pedido finalizado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Não", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(OrderStatus.this, "Cancelado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.mipmap.picture);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void hideOrder(final Integer position) {//Pass selected item position
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog=new AlertDialog.Builder(OrderStatus.this);
        alertDialog.setTitle("Olá, "+Common.currentUser.getName());
        alertDialog.setMessage("O pedido foi entregue?");
        alertDialog.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialog.dismiss();
              
                //**remove item from list at specific position**

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(OrderStatus.this, "Pedido finalizado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Não", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(OrderStatus.this, "Cancelado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setIcon(R.mipmap.picture);
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```